# How to create the tree view using angularjs and json?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How to add the child value when we checked the parent element? How to passing Checkbox value to javascript?

Comment: As @Madhu said, what have you tried? Here at Stack Overflow, we want to help, but we don't want to do it for you. Please provide the code that you've *already tried*. Learn more about asking questions in the [help center](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/).

Comment: I created tree view, but i can not add child value from in the textbox.

Comment: var app = angular.module('app', []);
function sampleController($scope){
 $scope.items=[
 {
  text:"item A",
  children:
  [
   {
     text:"item A-1",
     children:
     [
      {text:"item A-1-1"},
      {text:"item A-1-2"}
     ]
   }, 
   {text:"item A-2"},
   {text:"item A-3"}
  ]
 },
 {
  text:"item B",
  children:
  [
   {text:"item B-1"},
   {text:"item B-2"},  
   {
     text:"item B-3",
     children:
     [
      {text:"item B-3-1"},
      {text:"item B-3-2"}
     ]
   }, 
   {text:"item B-4"},
   {text:"item B-5"}
  ]
 }
 ]; 
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the code which you have been written let me know code.

Most probably you required to create one action and call it when you checked checkbox and this action push objects into $scope.items or you can use map in javascript for faster operation while fetching.